# Config the opencv in python 2.7 of MacOS

Tags: python, macos, opencv

Today I was installing the opencv by
homebrew install opencv
and then I try to import it by:

python

import cv2

and it return: No moudule named cv2

However, I try to import it by:

Python3

Import cv2

it works well.

I tried to install opencv again but homebrew said it has been installed.
Dont know what can I do now

Comment: It sounds like you're using the system version of `python2`, which doesn't look in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` for packages installed by brew. You should make sure to invoke `/usr/local/bin/python` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

copy cv2.so and cv.py to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/`
You can find this two files in `/usr/local/Cellar/opecv/../lib/python2.7`